# Can you get your cycling helmet wet?

Tags: helmets

[image]
I have bought this Bontrager rally helmet and I was wondering if it does any harm to it if it gets wet eg. In the rain

Comment: If you're concerned about getting wet head through the vents, then its possible to fit a shower cap either under the helmet or over the whole thing. Doesn't help much keeping the rest of you dry though.

Answer (score 12):

Of course no, it doesn't do any harm that the helmet gets wet **in WATER**.

It is made of various plastics, which *per se* are insensitive to water, and also it is supposed to be worn even though the cyclist is cycling under rain or snow.

Also, your sweat is basically water and some salts. If water was dangerous to helmets you should not sweat when wearing them :)

Just avoid that it gets wet by organic solvents (acetone, benzene, etc.), as they might attack some of the plastic and drastically alter their mechanical properties, leaving to your head the same protection offered by a shopper. The advice to not paint or put stickers on the helmet comes from the above point, as some paints or glue can contain non suitable solvents.

Comment: Thanks mate so I can ride in the poaring rain with no problems just dry it out after?

Comment: @sean yes - same as you'd do for your bike lights or your shoes or gloves.

Comment: My current helmet has been in pouring rain maybe 15 times, and very sweaty probably 75 times.  I just keep it in the house somewhere it can dry out on its own (rather than in the garage where the humidity can very quite a bit), and I've never had a problem.